# Getting values from sympy solve list

Tags: python, list, sympy

I've been trying to get the x & y values from a "solve list". So I have this code where I solve for x and y from a eq:

```
from sympy import * 

x,y = symbols('x,y')

eq = -2*x**2 + 4*x - y**2 - 2*y

pdx = diff(eq, x)

pdy = diff(eq, y)

result = solve((Eq(pdx, 0), Eq(pdy, 0)), x, y)

print(result)
```

And the output is:

`{x: 1, y: -1}`

I would like to assign the output x and y values to a new x0 and y0, but I don't know how.

I have been trying somthing like:

`x0 = tuple(result)[0]`

but then it makes x0 to x and not 1!

Comment: x0 = result['x']?

Comment: That worked! just without the ''. So x0 = result[x]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`x0 = result[x]` worked for me, thanks to @The6thSense